# SSIS Export Access Table To File - Incorrect Data Type

Tags: ssis

I'm exporting an MSAccess table to a flat file using a simple Data Flow Task in VStudio SSIS. My problem is a column, defined in the table as Number(Double) is being forced to scientific notation, no matter what data type I select in the destination flat file connection manager.

Is there someplace else to determine the source data type?

I have a source connection manager where I defined the MSAccess file connection and the table to use. Then I have a destination flat file connection, which is where I have the ability to select data types and do the mappings.

Answer (score 0):

In the destination connection manager, try the float data type(if you haven't already).

Comment: I have tried DTR_4 - single precision float (which was applied by default), DTR_8, which is double precision float, and even DT_STR (STRING), with the same result.

Comment: I wonder if adding IMEX=1 to the Access connection string would help...from the comments here http://www.builderau.com.au/program/sqlserver/soa/How-to-import-an-Excel-file-into-SQL-Server-2005-using-Integration-Services/0,339028455,339285948,00.htm

Note that one of the commenters also made a registry change so that the Jet engine would look at more rows of data in determining data type.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Data Flow Task source in "Advanced Editor".

Go to "Input/Output Properties".

Select "Source Output/Output Columns".

Change the data type of the column to DT_STR.